# NDB Datastore: Data Modeling for a Job website

Tags: google-app-engine, data-structures, app-engine-ndb

What is the best way to model data for a job website which has the following elements:

- Two types of user accounts: `JobSeekers` and `Employers`
- Employers can create `JobPost` entities.
- Each `JobSeeker` can create a `Resume` entity, and many `JobApplication` entities.

  - `JobSeekers` can create a `JobApplication` entity which is related to a `JobPost` entity.

    - A `JobPost` entity may receive many `JobApplication` entities.
    - A JobSeeker may only create one `JobApplication` entity per `JobPost` entity.
  - A `Resume` contains one or more instances of `Education`, `Experience`, using `ndb.StructuredProperty(repeated = True)`.

    - Each `Education` contains the following `ndb.StringProperty` fields: `institution`, `certification`, `area_of_study`
    - While each `Experience` contains: `workplace`, `job_title`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a skeleton model that meets your requirements:

```
class Employer(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.UserProperty()

class JobPost(ndb.Model):
    employer = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Employer)

class JobSeeker(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.UserProperty()
    def apply(self, job_post):
        if JobApplication.query(JobApplication.job_seeker == self.key,
                                JobApplication.job_post == job_post).count(1) == 1:
            raise Exception("Already applied for this position")
        ...

class Resume(ndb.Model):
    job_seeker = ndb.KeyProperty(JobSeeker)
    education = ndb.JsonProperty()
    experience = ndb.JsonProperty()

class JobApplication(ndb.Model):
    job_seeker = ndb.KeyProperty(JobSeeker)
    job_post = ndb.KeyProperty(JobPost)
```

Notes:

- `Employer` and `JobSeeker` have the built-in `UserProperty` to identify and allow them to login.
- `Resume` uses `JsonProperty` for `education` and `experience` to allow for more fields in the future.  You can assign a Python dictionary to this field, for example
  `resume.education = {'institution': 'name', 'certification': 'certificate', 'area_of_study': 'major', 'year_graduated': 2013, ...}`
  (I have personally found StructuredProperty to be more pain than gain, and I avoid it now.)
- Limiting a `JobSeeker` to only one `JobApplication` can be done with the method `apply()` which checks the `JobApplication` table for existing applications.